# How to ping machines behind an openvpn client router

Tags: routing, openvpn

I've a network located in 3 phisical places. 
In the first place I've a PC called PC1 configured as OpenVpn Client with a 10.8.0.3 ip address.
In the second place I've a Router configured as OpenVpn Server.
In the third place I've another router configured as OpenVpn Client.
Actually the OpenVpn works correctly, from PC1 I can ping 10.8.0.2.

```
  Router 1             |        Router 2
 ________________      |       ________________
| OpenVpnServer  |     |      |  OpenVpnClient |
| 10.8.0.1       |<-----------| 10.8.0.2       |
|________________|     |      | ---------------|
       /|\             |      | 169.254.11.254 |
        |              |      |________________|
________|______________|             /|\
        |              |              |
      PC 1 (10.8.0.3)  |            PC2 (169.254.11.23)
  Openvpn client       |
```

What I want to achive is to ping PC2 from PC1 by executing a ping on 169.254.11.23.
I think that it's necessary to modify routing tables according to my needs but I don't know how to do it. 
I tried to modify some route rules on the PC1 and on router 1 and 2 but without success.
Following I will report the actual configuration of each point of the network:

PC1 
routes:

```
    Route attive:
     Indirizzo rete             Mask          Gateway     Interfaccia Metri
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.138.3   192.168.139.43     25
         10.8.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.8.0.3    276
         10.8.0.3  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.3    276
       10.8.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.3    276
         25.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link       25.36.0.209   9256
      25.36.0.209  255.255.255.255         On-link       25.36.0.209   9256
   25.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       25.36.0.209   9256
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
     169.254.11.0    255.255.255.0         10.8.0.1         10.8.0.3     21
    192.168.138.0    255.255.254.0         On-link    192.168.139.43    281
   192.168.139.43  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.139.43    281
  192.168.139.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.139.43    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       25.36.0.209   9256
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.8.0.3    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.139.43    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       25.36.0.209   9256
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.3    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.139.43    281
```

Openvpn client cfg:

```
    client
ip-win32 ipapi
;float
dev tun
proto udp
remote xxx.duckdns.org 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
mute-replay-warnings
ca ca.crt
cert client4.crt
key client4.key
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Router1 routes:

```
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.20    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vlan2
10.8.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
127.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vlan2
```

openvpn server cfg:

```
    push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

dev tun0
proto udp
keepalive 10 60
dh /tmp/openvpn/dh.pem
ca /tmp/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /tmp/openvpn/cert.pem
key /tmp/openvpn/key.pem
```

router 2 routes:

```
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.64.64.64     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
10.8.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun11
169.254.11.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
127.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
default         10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ppp0
```

openvpn client cfg:

```
    resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
mute-replay-warnings
ca ca.crt
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Comment: Getting good answers requires a clear and useful question which is [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681)  and contains sufficient details about your actual configuration to provide you with a good solution. - Please edit and  improve your question to address those points or run the risk of leaving your problem unresolved.

Comment: Ok, I think that now the question is more clear. Thank you

Comment: I'm not well versed in OpenVPN and your diagram is useful with regards to describing what you aim to achieve, tbut typically to be able to answer your question we need to see you actual setup, the contents op VPN server configuration file (taking into account [what info you need to obfuscate](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/963/) ).

Comment: ok, that's all the info I've.. I don't added before because i think that it could be confusing